# login page session info prevent double login

Tags: php, session, session-variables

So I am trying to prevent users from logging in twice by disabling the login page if they manage to get there at all.

At the top of my page, I have:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] != true){
run page...
}
else {
    echo "You are already logged in! If you believe this in a error, please let us know. Thanks!";
}
?>
```

Is seems pretty straight forward, but even after I logout via the logout script below, it echoes the 'you are already logged in'

Here is my logout script:

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
```

on my login page, I have:

```
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $id;
$_SESSION['sess_username'] = $xusername;
$_SESSION['sess_gender'] = $gender;
$_SESSION['sess_homelat'] = $homelat;
$_SESSION['sess_homelng'] = $homelng;
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
```

But this would not seem to be the issue.

I am developing locally, if this changes anything?

EDIT: The solution so far seems to be in deleting the cookie, as posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the clearing out of the session variables backwards to the `session_destroy`. You'll want to do this instead:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
```

[As per the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), you could also delete the session cookie to ensure everything is destroyed fully:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION = array();
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = false; // Just in case

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

session_destroy();
```

On your login page, do you have `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;` surrounded by any if-statement at all? Check to see if it's being inadvertently set by adding a `die('loggedin session var has been set!');` right after it.

Comment: thanks, Ill give that a go. changing the order didn't do anything (although it certainly makes sense).

Comment: @ambe5960 Maybe `$_SESSION['loggedin']` is being set somewhere else without you realizing it? What if you tried `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;` after `$_SESSION = array();`? If that doesn't work, there's definitely something else resetting your `$_SESSION['loggedin']`